# Hadoop Filesystem shell returning -1 following successful execution

Tags: java, hadoop, ssh, hdfs

I'm trying to create a directory using the "hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/19491/testfolder" with the following code:

```
        Session session = createSSHSession();
        ChannelExec channelExec = null;
        channelExec = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
        channelExec.setCommand("hdfs dfs -mkdir -p hdfs://user/19491/testfolder");
        channelExec.connect();
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channelExec.getInputStream()));
        String text;
        while((text=br.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println("Text is:"+text);
        }
        int exitStatus = channelExec.getExitStatus();
        System.out.println("Exit status:"+exitStatus);
```

After running this code, the folder is created but the exit status returned is -1. Which according to this [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.html#mkdir) suggests a error. Why is this so? The folder is created so shouldn't it return 0?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are using jsch) `getExitStatus` returns -1 when the command has not finished.

http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExitStatus()

I think the function is called slightly before `hdfs` command finishes. This [example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec) waits until the channel is closed.